# How to split the edit window in ZeroBrane Studio

Tags: zerobrane

How do I split the edit window in ZeroBrane Studio,
either vertical or horizontal?

Is there a short cut to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can drag the editor tab to a different location in the editor panel to split the window. If you're looking for split editing of the same file, then you can use the [cloneview plugin](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBranePackage/blob/master/cloneview.lua), which supports this. You'll see "Clone Horizontally" and "Clone Vertically" items available in the editor tab menu (right click on an editor tab) after [installing the plugin](https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-plugin#plugin-installation).

Comment: "You can drag the editor tab to a different location in the editor panel to split the window." I cannot get this to work. Is this available in v1.90? Also, the text on splitting windows in https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-tips-and-tricks#merge-and-split-windows-and-tabs talk about "notebook", but I have no clue what that is about. Could you be more specific? Thanks.

Comment: Try clicking on the tab, dragging it to the right (over the scroll-bar area or close to it) and then releasing the mouse. It should split that tab into a separate panel. You can then re-arrange tabs by moving them between panels (and merge panels by moving the last tab). You should be able to move the tab in any direction, just make sure you release it close to the boundary.

Comment: Ah! Now I got it. Thank you. I use a dark theme and the blue indicator is not very visible (to me). But now I know how it works, so I don't need any indicator.  Thanks again. This will be a performance boost to my work flow.